# Excel Function for Multiple IF

Tags: excel, vba

I created a "IF Formula" in excel and wanted to convert that formula in function and i use the below mentioned code but it gave me #VALUE! error:

```
Function AccountType(dCell As Variant) As Long
If dCell = Left(dCell, 4) = "0321" Then
 AccountType = "12 - ABC type
ElseIf dCell = Left(dCell, 3) = "021" Then
 AccountType = "543 - XYZ type"
Else
 AccountType = "Logic Missing"
        End If
End Function
```

And this the IF formula I'm trying to convert in function:

```
 =IF(LEFT(L3,4)=0321," 12 - ABC type",
 IF(LEFT(L3,3)=021," 543 - XYZ type",
 IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("T56_",L3))=FALSE,MID(L3,SEARCH("T56_",L3),19),
 IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("MCW",L3))=FALSE,MID(L3,SEARCH("MCW_",L3),10),
 "Logic Missing"))))
```

I just include the 4 IF's from the formula; but I have more than 10 IF logic in the actual formula.

Comment: you are missing a `"` on the third line.

Comment: `As String`, not `As Long`.... I commented this already on your earlier question.

Comment: and remove both `dCell =`